# How to add a text drop-down menu on a image sprite menu?

Tags: css, image, menu, sprite

I am using an image sprite and adjusted it with CSS property Background Position. I need to put a text drop-down menu for one element named Produkte. I would like to get some help on this and it would be highly appreciable..

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="sixteen columns menu-container">
            <div id="wrapper">
            <nav>
                <ul id="awesome-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-one active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-two" id="product-clk">Produkte</a>                                      
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">kolors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hanchustfen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Kanalkannan</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Interaktive Online  Prasentation</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-three">Zubehor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-four">Angebote</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-five">Downloads</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-six">Impressum</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End: Sixteen Columns and Menu Container -->
```

CSS CODE:

```
.menu-container {
    height: 90px;
    background: url(../images/menu-bg.png) repeat-x #d4d4d4;
    box-shadow: 2px #888888;
}

ul#awesome-menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 66px;
}

ul#awesome-menu li { 
    display: inline; 
}

ul#awesome-menu li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 75px;
    background: url(../images/menu.png);
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-one {
    width: 96px; background-position: 0 0;  
  }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-two {
    width: 138px; background-position: -96px 0; 
  }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-three {
    width: 126px; background-position: -234px 0; 
  }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-four {
    width: 136px; background-position: -360px 0;  
  }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-five {
    width: 146px; background-position: -496px 0; 
  }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-six {
    width: 157px; background-position: -642px 0; 
  }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-one:hover, ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-one:focus {
        background-position: 0 -76px;   
    }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-two:hover, ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-two:focus {
        background-position: -96px -76px;   
    }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-three:hover, ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-three:focus {
        background-position: -234px -76px;  
    }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-four:hover, ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-four:focus {
        background-position: -360px -76px;  
    }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-five:hover, ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-five:focus {
        background-position: -496px -76px;  
    }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-six:hover, ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-six:focus {
        background-position: -642px -76px;  
    }

ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-one.active {
        background-position: 0 -76px;   
}
```

till first level menu is working fine. Please help me

Comment: Can you provide a working jsfiddle?

Comment: code snippet/ jsfiddle / page URL would be great to debug

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking for a drop-down icon for your 'Produkte' link, since it has got a sub-menu inside it. So if that's your query try using this:

**HTML:**

```
<li><a href="#" class="nav-two" id="product-clk"><span class="drop-ic"></span>Produkte</a>
```

**CSS**

```
ul#awesome-menu li a.nav-two { position: relative; }

.drop-ic { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; background: url('../images/your-image-name') no-repeat 0 0; width: 26px; height: 24px; }
```

Set the top and right value to your requirement, hope it helps you.